# How do I upgrade Phonegap 1.8 to 1.9 for Blackberry?

Tags: cordova, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I've been using Eclipse and Phonegap 1.8 to develop BlackBerry Playbook apps, and the entire process has been working wonderfully.

I'd like to update to Phonegap 1.9 but I have been unsuccessful. I've checked the Phonegap docs for info but that didn't help. I can't supply exact error messages right now, and I won't be able to get to my development system for a few more days.

I'm probably missing something basic in the updating process. Can someone please outline the steps I need to go through to do this upgrade?

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure how you've set up your eclipse project for developing with playbook apps, but essentially the only thing you need to do is update the cordova-x.x.x.js file. Careful not to use the 2.0.0 version for playbook as there's an error in that version. I hope that helps!

Also, if merely updating the cordova-x.x.x.js file is still giving you problems, I'd suggest taking out the '-' in the file name. Playbook doesn't like to play with special chars in file names.

Comment: Hi Tim   You're right about the "-", replacing "-" with "." worked.   I stumbled onto that trick after about 4 hours of frustration last night. As a last resort I tried creating an Android project, then imported that project into my BlackBerry workspace and it worked properly. That got me curious and after some digging I realized the "-" seemed to be the cause.   Thanks for confirming it for me.  Rob